# Vite dev proxy not proxying

Tags: vuejs3, vite, nuxt3

I have a nuxt3 web app. For dev purposes I want to proxy requests from "/whatever" to "localhost:3033".
I tried doing that via the vite server options as described in their docs (https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy). So my nuxt.config.ts looks like this:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    vite: {
        server: {
            proxy: {
                '/whatever': 'http://localhost:3033/',
            }
        }
    }
})
```

After changing the config I restarted `yarn dev` to make sure everything is reloaded.

If I however go to "http://localhost:3000/whatever" I just get the "Welcome to Nuxt" page (I tested this in an empty project). Or if I do it in my main project with `pages: true`, I get a 404.

Any ideas on where the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem bz not using the vite devProxy, but the one by nitro as follows:

```
 nitro: {
    devProxy: {
      "/whatever": "http://127.0.0.1:3033/",
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

in nuxt 3 rc this works for me:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({  
    nitro: {
        devProxy: {
            "/devApi": {
                target:"your url",
                changeOrigin: true,
                prependPath: true,
            }
        }
    },
})
```